# Removing columns if values are not in an ascending order python

Tags: python, pandas

Given a data like so:

| Symbol | One | Two |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 28.75 | 25.10 |
| 2 | 29.00 | 25.15 |
| 3 | 29.10 | 25.00 |

I want to drop the column which does not have its values in an ascending order (though I want to allow for gaps) across all rows. In this case, I want to drop column 'Two'.I tried to following code with no luck:

```py
df.drop(df.columns[df.all(x <= y for x,y in zip(df, df[1:]))])
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dropping those columns that give at least one (`any`) negative value (`lt(0)`) when their values are differenced by 1 lag (`diff(1)`) after `NaN`s are neglected (`dropna`):

```py
columns_to_drop = [col for col in df.columns if df[col].diff(1).dropna().lt(0).any()] 
df.drop(columns=columns_to_drop)
```

```
   Symbol    One
0       1  28.75
1       2  29.00
2       3  29.10
```

Answer (score 0):

An expression that works with gaps (NaN)

```py
A.loc[:, ~(A.iloc[1:, :].reset_index() > A.iloc[:-1, :].reset_index()).any()]
```

Without gaps it would be equivalent to

```py
A.loc[:, (A.iloc[1:, :].reset_index() <= A.iloc[:-1, :].reset_index()).all()]
```

Without loops to take better advantage of the framework for bigger dataframes.

- `A.iloc[1:, :]` returns a dataframe without the first line
- `A.iloc[:-1, :]` returns a dataframe without the last line
- Slices in a dataframe keep the indices for corresponding rows, so the different slices have different indices, `reset_index` will create another index counting `[0,1,...]`, thus making the two sides of the inequality compatible. You can pass `drop=True` if you want to remove the previous index.
- Any (implicitly with `axis=0`) check for every column if any value is true, if so, it means that a number was followed by another.
- `A.loc[:, mask]` select the columns where mask is true, drops the columns where mask is false.

The logic is could be read as `not any value smaller than its predecessor` or `all values greater than its predecessor`.

Answer (score 0):

Check out code and only logic is:

```
map(lambda i: list(df[i]) == sorted(list(df[i])), df.columns)]
```

---

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Symbol': [1, 2, 3],
        'One': [28.75, 29.00, 29.10],
        'Two': [25.10, 25.15, 25.10],
    }
)

print(df.loc[:,map(lambda i: list(df[i]) == sorted(list(df[i])), df.columns)])
```